# Sitecore 9.1.1 remote events not executing on CM server

Tags: events, event-queue

I am trying to get a remote event fired from `CD server to CM server` and then CM server to create the item required in Sitecore 9.1.1. I can see the event gets added to the database but it never gets executed. Below are my configuration and code

**Config:**

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore>
    <hooks role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement">
      <hook type="Sitecore.Feature.PageFeedback.Events.UpdatePageRatingHook, Sitecore.Feature.PageFeedback"></hook>
    </hooks>
    <event name="updatepagerating:remote">
      <handler type="Sitecore.Feature.PageFeedback.Events.UpdatePageRatingEventHandler, Sitecore.Feature.PageFeedback" method="OnUpdatePageRatingRemote"></handler>
    </event>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**Hook:**

```
namespace Sitecore.Feature.PageFeedback.Events
{
  public class UpdatePageRatingHook : IHook
  {
    public void Initialize()
    {
      Log.Info("Subscribing to updatePage rating event", this);
      EventManager.Subscribe(new Action<UpdatePageRatingModel>(UpdatePageRatingEventHandler.Run));
    }
  }
}
```

**Event args:**

```
namespace Sitecore.Feature.PageFeedback.Events
{
  public class UpdatePageRatingEventArgs : EventArgs, IPassNativeEventArgs
  {
    private UpdatePageRatingModel _evt;

    public UpdatePageRatingEventArgs(UpdatePageRatingModel evt)
    {
      _evt = evt;
    }

    public Guid pageId
    {
      get { return _evt.pageId; }
    }

    public int Score
    {
      get { return _evt.Score; }
    }

    public Guid? FeedbackReference
    {
      get { return _evt.FeedbackReference; }
    }
  }
}
```

**EventHandler:**

```
namespace Sitecore.Feature.PageFeedback.Events
{
  public class UpdatePageRatingEventHandler
  {
    private readonly IPageFeedbackService _feedbackService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IPageFeedbackService>();
    /// <summary>
    /// The method is the method that you need to implement as you do normally
    /// </summary>
    public virtual void OnUpdatePageRatingRemote(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Log.Info("Executing page rating event",this);
      if (e is UpdatePageRatingEventArgs)
      {
        var args = e as UpdatePageRatingEventArgs;
        Log.Info("submitting stars feedback", this);
        _feedbackService.SubmitStarsFeedback(new StarsFeedbackModel()
        {
          PageId = args.pageId,
          FeedbackReference = args.FeedbackReference,
          Score = args.Score
        });
      }
    }

    // This methos is used to raise the local event
      public static void Run(UpdatePageRatingModel evt)
      {
        Log.Info("Raising event locally for pagefeedback", typeof(UpdatePageRatingEventHandler));
        UpdatePageRatingEventArgs args = new UpdatePageRatingEventArgs(evt);
        Event.RaiseEvent("updatepagerating:remote", new object[] {args});
      }
    }
  }
```

**Creating an event:**

```
public ID StartsFeedBackEvent(StarsFeedbackModel model)
    {
      var database = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web");
      var eventQueue = database.RemoteEvents.EventQueue;
      eventQueue.QueueEvent(new UpdatePageRatingModel()
      {
        pageId = model.PageId,
        FeedbackReference = model.FeedbackReference,
        Score = model.Score
      });
      return new ID(model.FeedbackReference.Value);
    }
```

**Event entry in Database:**

[image]